# NHibernate - eager fetch a collection

Tags: nhibernate, eager-loading

I'm creating a HQL query that uses eager fetching for some collections and properties. This is the query:

```
var result = Session.CreateQuery("from Match m left join fetch m.User u left join fetch u.ProfileItems pi where m.User.Id = :p1")
        .SetParameter("p1", user.Id)
        .List<Match>().ToList();
```

This works well. Using NHProfiler, I can see that it produces the following SQL query:

```
select (...) from `Match` match0_
       left outer join `User` user1_
         on match0_.UserId = user1_.Id
       left outer join `ProfileItem` profileite2_
         on user1_.Id = profileite2_.User_id
where  match0_.UserId =? p0
```

Now, I can iterate over the result of `Match` instances or even `User` instances like this:

```
foreach (User u in result.Select(m => m.User))
{
  // .. do something
}
```

... and it will not hit the database again.

However, the User object has a property that is not mapped to the database, IsOnline. This does some calculation using the current date. As soon as I use this property in an expression, the database will be hit. For example:

```
int i = result.Count(m => m.MatchingUser.IsOnline);
```

... will hit the database for every user, in my case 10 times, using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM   `User` user0_ WHERE  user0_.Id =? p0
```

I have two main questions:

1. Why is this?
2. How do I prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: How does your mapping look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a copy&paste error, you are using a different property (MatchingUser) from the one you fetched (User)

Comment: Seriously, you have no idea how stupid this makes me feel :-) This took like 2 hours of my time yesterday. Thanks for reading my post in detail.